# What's the filetype of winbar? Is it a kind of window?

Tags: vim-windows

As title. I have some plugins that conflict with each other. If I can know the filetype of winbar then I save much time debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The Termdebug Winbar is not a window and does not contain a buffer.  Instead it's based on a built-in vim feature `:menu`.

```
" Install the window toolbar in the current window.
func s:InstallWinbar()
  if has('menu') && &mouse != ''
    nnoremenu WinBar.Step   :Step<CR>
    nnoremenu WinBar.Next   :Over<CR>
    nnoremenu WinBar.Finish :Finish<CR>
    nnoremenu WinBar.Cont   :Continue<CR>
    nnoremenu WinBar.Stop   :Stop<CR>
    nnoremenu WinBar.Eval   :Evaluate<CR>
    call add(s:winbar_winids, win_getid(winnr()))
  endif
endfunc
```

Comment: So its full name is "Termdebug Winbar" or you meant only the winbar for termbuf?

Comment: no, winbar is a separate feature that other plugins can use as well. I rather like to hear what kind of conflicts you are facing with winbars. Note: on neovim, winbar is a slightly different feature than what upstream vim provides.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh no! then I gave my question the wrong tag. I was asking about winbar in neovim. I thought winbar was something inherited from vim.